# return certain field of wso2 esb response

Tags: wso2, response, sequence, wso2-esb

I have some api resource in wso2 esb. I want to custom the response so it will be return just certain field that i want. For example i have original response like this :

```
{
   "studentsResponse": {
      "return": {
          "listStudent": [
             {
                "id": "16519",
                "name": "VELLEN OKTAVIARA"
             },
             {
                "id": "16520",
                "name": "ADINDA ALFIYUNISA SELANIAR"
             },
          ]
       }
   }
}
```

how can i get the `listStudent` field without the `return` and `studentsResponse` field.

this is my `outsequence` code :

```
    <outSequence>
        <property name="messageType" scope="axis2" type="STRING" value="application/json"/>
        <send />
    </outSequence>
```

I just convert it to json, what should i do to my outsequence ?

thanks

Answer (score 1):

after a couple minute I figured it out.

I just need to add a payload factory like this :

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>$1</format>
            <args>
                <arg expression="$.studentsResponse.return.listStudent"
                    evaluator="json"></arg>
            </args>
        </payloadFactory>
```

Comment: You can also do the same using enrich mediator. If you are trying to extract a part of the payload enrich works well. Payload factory will be for transforming the payload. However, its really your choice :) Both mediators can do the job.

Comment: hi @maheeka actually i have other problems here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40694390/soap-messages-are-not-sent-using-wso2-esb-rest-api
 could you please take a look there, thanks :)